# Seeking locations data of all police stations in India

Tags: data-request, geospatial, government, india, police

I want to get the locations of all the police stations in India. There is definitely some data which is present in the OpenStreetMap which I am able to crawl. However, there are about 15,579 police stations in the country and only about 4000 are present in the osm bulk data.

How can I get the data of all the other police stations?

Any kind of procedure even including manual effort will suffice.

Comment: When you have the data, consider uploading it to OpenStreetMap

Comment: hi - welcome. do you have a source for "_15,579 police stations in the country_"?

Comment: Have you looked in Geonames? You need `featureCode=S.PP and countryCode=IN`. Unfortunately there's no online search of this granularity so you need to grep through a dump file.

Comment: Another API you could explore is the [Google Places](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/places) but you'll almost certainly need to pay due to the volume of queries you will make?

Answer (score 2):

I'll put the OSM queries here as an answer, although the person asking the question has stated that OSM doesn't have nearly all entries.

There are two main keywords to query:

- [`"police=*"`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:police)
- [`"amenity=police"`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:amenity%3Dpolice)

https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/11f0 (without country-filter or bounding box)

> Loaded – nodes: 13505, ways: 1516, relations: 16
>
> Displayed – pois: 3530, lines: 1, polygons: 1472

[image]

```
[out:json][timeout:100];

// gather results
(
  // query part for: “police=*”
  node["police"]({{bbox}});
  way["police"]({{bbox}});
  relation["police"]({{bbox}});
  
  // query part for: “amenity=police”
  node["amenity"="police"]({{bbox}});
  way["amenity"="police"]({{bbox}});
  relation["amenity"="police"]({{bbox}});
  
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

---

[filter overpass-turbo by country](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/127319/112869)